# Strongly typed RouteWithProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to create a variant on the common PropsRoute component in TypeScript with strong typing on the props for the component to be rendered. The code below seems close but still results in an error.

```
interface PropsRouteProps<P> extends RouteProps {
  component: ComponentType<P>
  withProps: P
}

export const PropsRoute = <P extends object>({
  component: WrappedComponent,
  withProps,
  ...routeProps
}: PropsRouteProps<P>): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...routeProps}
      render={childProps => {
        return <WrappedComponent {...childProps} {...withProps} />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

The error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/containers/pages/accounts/AccountInfo.tsx:88:13

TS2322: Type 'typeof AccountDetails' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{ details: {  [[DetailsObjectDefinition]] } | undefined; loading: boolean; }>'.

Type 'typeof AccountDetails' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ details: {  [[DetailsObjectDefinition]] } | undefined; loading: boolean; }>'.

Type 'typeof AccountDetails' provides no match for the signature '(props: { details: {  [[DetailsObjectDefinition]] }} | undefined; loading: boolean; } & { ...; }, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | null'.
```

The calling method:

```
<PropsRoute
  path={`${match.path}/details`}
  component={AccountDetails}
  withProps={{
    details: this.state.details.data,
    loading: this.state.details.loading
  }}
/>
```

The specific component to insert props into in this case (for completeness).

```
interface Params {
  email: string
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<Params> {
  details: AccountDetailsResponse | undefined
  loading: boolean
}

export class AccountDetails extends PureComponent<Props> {
```

Again, here I'd like to have, for example, `details` throw a compiler error when it's type does not match the defined props for the Account details component.

Typescript 3.0.1 - Strict mode

Comment: Could you post the full error ? Use `"noErrorTruncation": true` to get the full error if you don't see it by default. I tried your example and after filling in the missing pieces it seems to work

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Updated Q with full error.

Comment: In `PropsRoute`, where is `WrappedComponent` defined?  Also please add the declaration of `AccountDetails` so we can see its props type.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen WrappedComponent is aliased from the `component` parameter (it's not a type there, I should just rename it) and AccountDetails is just a regular component with Props corresponding to those in the withProps object.

Comment: If AccountDetails were as you claim, there would be no error... we need to see the declaration to understand why there is an error.  It may be that AccountDetails requires the childProps in addition to the withProps and your definition of PropsRouteProps isn't accounting for this.